# Perl install_driver(Oracle) failed: - Can't load '../DBD/Oracle/Oracle.dll' for module DBD::Oracle Win64

Tags: oracle, perl

Having issues with Perl 5.20.2 and Oracle::DBD, getting following error when trying to connect to Ora 12C DB, run out of ideas on how to identify what is wrong here.

```
install_driver(Oracle) failed: Can't load 'C:/Perl/site/lib/auto/DBD/Oracle/Oracle.dll' for module DBD::Oracle: load_file:%1 is not a valid Win32 application at C:/Perl/lib/DynaLoader.pm line 194.
  at (eval 72) line 3.
 Compilation failed in require at (eval 72) line 3
```

My environment is as follows

- Perl -v - This is perl 5, version 20, subversion 2 (v5.20.2) built for MSWin32-x86-multi-thread-64int
- OS is Win 2008 R2 SP1
- Ora client is 12.1.0 (64 bit)

*Windows Environmental variables*

ORACLE_HOME=C:\Oracle12c\product\12.1.0\client_1

Path=C:\Oracle12c\product\12.1.0\client_1\bin;C:\Perl\site\bin;C:\Perl\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPo
werShell\v1.0\;c:\dmake;D:\NTRESKIT

TNS_ADMIN=C:\Oracle12c\product\12.1.0\client_1\bin

Comment: Did you install the OCI component of the Oracle client? Are you installing the Oracle Instant Client for 12c?

Comment: Oracle Client 12c is installed and I do see the ocu.dll in the <ORACLE_HOME>12.1.0\client_1\BIN folder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out...issue was not a files permission issue, the clue was in the  "**...not a valid Win32 application**" verbiage.

I was using Ora 64 bit client instead of 32-bit, removed the Oracle 12c 64-bit client and installed Oracle 12c 32-bit client (you can also install the 11g driver (apparently an Oracle client supports one version back and one version forward)).

I required the full 12c Ora client installer as I need access to the database tools like sqlloader, **note** that there is a bug in the 12c Oracle 32-bit installer, had to modify the install/oraparam.ini and replace MSVCREDIST_LOC=vcredist_x64.exe with MSVCREDIST_LOC=vcredist_x86.exe, took me a while to find the installer, link here, http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterpriseedition/downloads/database12c-win64-download-2297732.html , 32-bit driver at bottom of url, hopefully they will fix the installer)

Also, very important to also add an ORACLE_HOME Win env path, I also added the Oracle client to the Path and ensured that it was before the Perl entries in my Windows Path.

Comment: Thanks to the details you provided, it helped. It is the oracle client in the path that needs to match the bit of PERL. ORACLE_HOME had no impact on my installation.

Answer (score 0):

Along with the comment I made above, please look at the following here on stackoverflow:

[Perl_and_Oracle_DBD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294465/why-cant-my-perl-cgi-script-find-the-oracle-dbd?rq=1)

Comment: Ok, enough of the downvotes, please.  I was merely trying to suggest that, as pointed out in the link, the issue may be a permissions issue.

Comment: Thank you for assisting, it was not a files permission issue but an issue with having a Perl 32-bit version trying to communicate to an Ora 64-bit client, unfair you were given a down vote by someone for legitimately helping.

Comment: Thanks user2574678.  I am happy you figured it out and provided a resolution.  After all, that's what we are all here for!